# How to execute multiple shell commands using node.js?

Tags: node.js

Maybe I haven't groked the asynchronous paradigm yet, but I want to do something like this:

```
var exec, start;
exec = require('child_process').exec;
start = function() {
  return exec("wc -l file1 | cut -f1 -d' '", function(error, f1_length) {
    return exec("wc -l file2 | cut -f1 -d' '", function(error, f2_length) {
      return exec("wc -l file3 | cut -f1 -d' '", function(error, f3_length) {
        return do_something_with(f1_length, f2_length, f3_length);
      });
    });
  });
};
```

It seems a little weird to keep nesting those callbacks every time I want to add a new shell command. Isn't there a better way to do it?

Comment: Async JS to the rescue! https://github.com/caolan/async

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally use [TwoStep](https://github.com/xavi-/two-step) in these situations:

```
var TwoStep = require("two-step");
var exec, start;
exec = require('child_process').exec;
start = function() {
  TwoStep(
    function() {
      exec("wc -l file1 | cut -f1 -d' '", this.val("f1_length"));
      exec("wc -l file2 | cut -f1 -d' '", this.val("f2_length"));
      exec("wc -l file3 | cut -f1 -d' '", this.val("f3_length"));
    },
    function(err, f1_length, f2_length, f3_length) {
      do_something_with(f1_length, f2_length, f3_length);
    }
  );
};
```

That said, there are a ton of flow controll libraries out there.  I encourage you to try some out: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Modules#wiki-async-flow

Answer (score 7):

As Xavi said you can use TwoStep. On the other hand I use [Async JS](https://github.com/caolan/async) library. Your code may look like this:

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback) {
        exec("wc -l file1 | cut -f1 -d' '", function(error, f1_length) {
            if (error)
                return callback(error);
            callback(null, f1_length);
        });
    },
    function(callback) {
        exec("wc -l file2 | cut -f1 -d' '", function(error, f2_length) {
            if (error)
                return callback(error);
            callback(null, f2_length);
        });
    },
    function(callback) {
        exec("wc -l file3 | cut -f1 -d' '", callback);
    }
],
function(error, results) {
    /* If there is no error, then
       results is an array [f1_length, f2_length, f3_length] */
    if (error)
        return console.log(error);
    do_something_with(results);
});
```

Async gives tons of other options. Read the documentation and try it out! Note that for `f3_length` I just used `callback` when calling `exec`. You can do this with other calls as well (so your code will be shorter). I just wanted to show you how it works.